# My program stops working after it asks for a number

Tags: python

I'm incredibly new to python, so I apologize. I finally got rid of all the syntax errors, but now I just have no idea what I did wrong.

```
#Get the integers from the user
def main():
    largest = 0
    smallest = 0
    number = int(input('Input a number: '))
    while (number != -99):
        if number > largest:
             largest = number
        elif number < smallest:
             smallest = number
        number = int(input('Input a number, enter -99 to stop'))


# This module displays the smallest and largest integer entered.

def showNumber(smallest, largest):
    print('The smallest number is: ', smallest)
    print('The largest number is: ', largest)


#Call the main
main()
showNumber(smallest, largest)
```

This is supposed to ask the users for numbers until they put -99, then when they put -99 it's supposed to show the smallest and largest integer.
I know, it's so ugly. I can only use simple data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add additional 4 characters (spaces) to get it correct, which is by adding **indentation on one line**

```
def main():
    largest = 0
    smallest = 0
    while (number != -99):
        if number > largest:
            largest = number
        elif number < smallest:
            smallest = number
        number = int(input('Input a number, enter -99 to stop')) # Indent this line
```

You can compare your code with the code I show above. There are differences on the line I commented in, which is the amount of preceding space (the indentation)

Because otherwise the `while` loop will not end, since the `number` is updated *outside* the `while` loop.

Your *incorrect* code:

```
while (number != -99):
### The while loop starts here ###
    if number > largest:
        largest = number
    elif number < smallest:
        smallest = number
### The while loop ends here ###
number = int(input('Input a number, enter -99 to stop'))
```

So the `while` loop will never end, because it keeps comparing the same `number`, not comparing with the new input. In this case your program does not *stop* as you said, but rather it is *stuck* in what is called *infinite loop*

Python "code block" is defined by the indentation, so codes with the same level of indentation are considered to be in the same code block. So in order to your `number` to be changing each time you visit the loop, you need to put the `input` *inside* the while loop:

The *corrected* code:

```
while (number != -99):
### The while loop starts here ###
    if number > largest:
        largest = number
    elif number < smallest:
        smallest = number
    number = int(input('Input a number, enter -99 to stop'))
### The while loop ends here ###
```

*Update* (by @MERM):

You also have some problem on the `showNumber` function, as it's not using the variables from the `main` function. You can call the `showNumber` function in the `main` function like MERM has said:

```
def main():
    largest = 0
    smallest = 0
    while (number != -99):
        if number > largest:
            largest = number
        elif number < smallest:
            smallest = number
        number = int(input('Input a number, enter -99 to stop'))
    showNumber(smallest, largest)
```

And some words of encouragement, your code is not ugly. In fact it's good and concise, precisely solving the problem you're trying to solve. You seem to understand how you should lay out your logic in the code, even though you said you're "incredibly new to python".

Keep it up!

Comment: I'm sorry... can you explain that like I'm 5 please

Comment: Which part you don't understand?

Comment: the "12 characters to get it correct" someone else said that it's indent sensitive... so is that what you're saying too? Also, is my code correct that it will store the largest/smallest integer in those variables? edit:: ok, so I DID indent it correctly in my code (just wrote it wrong here. ) so i have no clue what I did wrong

Comment: Did you indent the `number = int(input(...))` correctly also? That's the important part.

Comment: And like @MERM has said also, you have problem in the `showNumber` function.

Comment: So, my last issue is that it's going to think the smallest number is 0, unless I enter a negative number. Obviously a way around that would be to enter an absurdly large number as the initial variable, but there must be a better way than that?

Comment: Indeed entering "an absurdly large number" is the most common way to get smallest number, as in computers we usually know what is the largest number possible. Another approach which I consider as second most common is by taking the first value of the input as the smallest number, like MERM did.

Answer (score 2):

Python is indent sensitive.

The elif and number needs to be at the same indentation as the if.  Also, you need to call showNumber from inside main otherwise smallest and largest are undefined (not in the same scope).

```
def main():
    number = int(input('Input a number: '))
    largest = number
    smallest = number
    while (number != -99):
        if (number > largest):
            largest = number
        elif (number < smallest):
            smallest = number
        number = int(input('Input a number, enter -99 to stop'))
    showNumber(smallest, largest)
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: I just checked, apparently I did indent it correctly (I just copied it wrong.) What else could it be ? :/

Comment: I updated my answer, after verifying that this version works as requested.

Comment: thank you so much! after I fixed the indent I did get that problem! you guys rock!

Comment: poopsauce. so, it keeps reading that the smallest number is 0.

Comment: Were you entering any numbers less then zero (your starting point for smallest)?  What you probably wanted is the smallest of the numbers entered.  With one number entered it is both the largest and smallest.  After that the newly entered numbers will be compared to this initial value. See the changes above.